# $.post versus $.ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I recently asked about how to post from a form with MVC. Thank you everyone for your help and advice.

I noticed some advice talking about using `$.post` and other people talk using `$.ajax`

Is there any difference and which is the best to use when I use Microsoft MVC version 3.

Please just reply with an answer for MVC.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery.post() is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: It would be nice to tell why using `$.ajax` is superior (like you can also define `error` function that you can't with `$.post`)

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: This is no longer true in jQuery 1.5.x, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @Lukáš Novotný: Indirectly you can provide `error` handler as well yes via jqXHR object but not directly by providing it to `$.post()` as a parameter. Although yes you're right it is possible.

Answer (score 4):

`$.post` calls `$.ajax` internally. However, I prefer using `$.ajax` since it looks better with proper indentation etc:

```
$.post('someURL', {
    my: 'data',
    more: 'data'
}, function(resp) {
    /* ... */
});
```

vs.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'someURL',
    dataType: '...',
    data: {
        my: 'data',
        more: 'data'
    },
    success: function(resp) {
        /* ... */
    }
});
```

The later is twice as long but much more readable IMO.

Comment: +1 I also **strictly always** use `$.ajax()` and none of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same. [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is just a shorthand to [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

> ```
> $.ajax({
>   type: 'POST',
>   url: url,
>   data: data,
>   success: success
>   dataType: dataType
> });
> ```